# RDF structure for online shopping product

Tags: html, rdf, rdfs, rdfa, vocabulary

What is rdf code and vocabulary for product list in online shopping website (html/html5) :

**For google and other search engine**

```
  <div class="product-list">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="product-name">PHP</div>
      <div class="product-type">Book</div>
      <div class="product-author"></div>
      <div class="product-price">11$</div>
      <div class="product-restriction-age">8-99</div>
      <div class="product-language">en</div>
      <div class="product-page-count">300</div>
      <div class="product-rate">4/10</div>
      <div class="product-size">154MB</div>
      <div class="product-download-count">2000</div>
      <div class="product-date">2014/04/10</div>
      <div class="product-isbn"></div>
   </div>

  <div class="item">

       ......

   </div>

  </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the [Good Relations ontology](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search engines from Google, Microsoft, Yahoo and Yandex sponsor the vocabulary [**Schema.org**](http://schema.org/), which can be used (and is [defined](http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html)) with HTML+RDFa.

This vocabulary provides suitable types for your case, like [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) and [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) (both based on the [GoodRelations](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/) vocabulary).

Of course each search engine decides which types to support for which use case. See for example Google’s documentation for their [Products rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products).